# Word to name both minima and maxima

Tags: single-word-requests, statistics

I would like to find a word to name the minima and maxima of a set of things. We have in French "extrêmes", but I don't find an equivalent in English, as far as my brief research is concerned.

Comment: **Extremes** should fit.

Comment: oh..thanks I guess. Can you make it an answer so I can label that question answered ?

Comment: You can also say "critical points."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some contexts, "poles" would apply (as in the opposite ends of a polarity). Similarly, "termini."

Somewhat obliquely: in literary criticism there is a figure of speech, "merismus," which refers to a totality by reference to its extremes; for example, "from A to Z," "from stem to stern," etc.